# Determine if property is from parent or child

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to write a simple function in the child class that *only* returns it's own keys (and not the parent).

```
class Parent{
    protected _parentAttribute!: string;
    constructor() {
        this._parentAttribute='test';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    childAttribute!: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("My unique child keys are:", Object.keys(this));
    }
}
let child=new Child();
```

Result:
`My unique child keys are: [_parentAttribute,childAttribute]`

Desired result: `My unique child keys are: [childAttribute]`

Is this possible?

Comment: Well you can make function in both classes which return keys and then in Child class will filter child array with this from Parent, so you end up with Child props only

Comment: this.keys (-) super.keys? Just a guess

Comment: @Estradiaz no, because `this.keys` probably will contain also parent

Comment: @Estradiaz - how exactly do you access super.keys? Something like Object.keys(super) does not work.

Comment: yeah no clue just tried - super needs a member access - so nvm sry

Comment: Have you tried, `Object.hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: @Rajesh - yes, does not preform differently than `Object.keys`

Comment: `Object.keys` return enumerable properties of an object. Not own properties

Answer (score 0):

First, create a variable at the top class and then in that variable, store the keys which are in the top class. Use a filter function inside the child class to filter the top variables. There's nothing bad in this approach as I think. The filter should work fine and this method should work every time.

```
class Parent{
    protected _parentAttribute: string;
    protected topKeys;
    constructor() {
        this._parentAttribute='test';
        this.topKeys = 'test' // asign something it so it comes in your property names
        let somevar = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this) // get all the properties
        this.topKeys = somevar // put them in this variable
    }

}
class Child extends Parent{
    public childAttribute: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.childAttribute = 'test'
        let keyofChild = Object.keys(this).filter(keys => !this.topKeys.includes(keys))
        console.log("My unique child keys are:", keyofChild); // childAttribute
    }
}

let child = new Child();
```

Answer (score -1):

Ended up getting it like this. However, feels hacky and I'm open to better answers:

```
class Parent{
    protected _parentAttribute: string;
    protected _parentAttribute2: string;
    protected _parentKeyList: Array<string>;
    constructor() {
        this._parentAttribute='test';
        this._parentAttribute2='another value';
        this._parentKeyList=['']; //Oddly necessary...
        this._parentKeyList=Object.keys(this); //Must be at the end of constructor
    }

class Child extends Parent{
    childAttribute: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        const uniqueKeys=_.difference(Object.keys(this),this._parentAttributes); //Using lodash
        console.log("My unique child keys are:", uniqueKeys);
    }

let child=new Child();
```

Comment: This is a bad hack. Try [getOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) instead

Comment: Why downvote? I told you my answer was hacky. Can you please show me an example? In childs constructor, `this.hasOwnProperty('childAttribute')` and `this.hasOwnProperty('_parentAttribute')` both return `true`. Additionally, `Object.keys(this)` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` both return the same thing. I am aware of the difference between these two functions but unsure how to apply that to this scenario. Hence, why I asked the question...

Comment: Not my vote but this is a very bad and non scalable hack. You have a lot of better options. Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` or Loop on `Object.keys` and check for `object.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Comment: @kmoney12 just to let you know - this hack is not needed - everything can be done in the child - ask if smth is unclear with my solution

Answer (score -1):

## after `super()` the child is equal to the parent as are its properties

#### TYPESCRIPT:

```
class Parent {
    _parentAttribute1: string = "test"
    _parentAttribute2 = 'test';
    constructor() {
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    getParentPropertyNames(): Array<string>{
      delete this.parentPropertyNames;
      return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)
    }

    // this is the magic as it get called immediatly after super()
    parentPropertyNames: Array<string> = this.getParentPropertyNames()
    // </magic>

    childAttribute1 = 'test';
    childPropertyNames!: string[]
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

  get uniqueNames(){
    this.childPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)
        //@ts-ignore
        .filter(name => !this.parentPropertyNames.includes(name)) // wastefull computation

    console.log(this.childPropertyNames)
    return this.childPropertyNames
  }
}
let child = new Child();
child.uniqueNames
```

#### parsed for running on SO

```js
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this._parentAttribute1 = "test";
        this._parentAttribute2 = 'test';
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // this is the magic as it get called immediatly after super()
        this.parentPropertyNames = this.getParentPropertyNames();
        // </magic>
        this.childAttribute1 = 'test';
    }
    getParentPropertyNames() {
        delete this.parentPropertyNames;
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
    }
    get uniqueNames() {
        this.childPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)
            //@ts-ignore
            .filter(name => !this.parentPropertyNames.includes(name)); // wastefull computation
        console.log(this.childPropertyNames);
        return this.childPropertyNames;
    }
}
let child = new Child();
child.uniqueNames;
```